# Change Input type with javascript, everywhere it could be

Tags: iframe, input, types, frame

I would like to change Input type with javascript, everywhere it could be, even in an eventual frameset / Iframe.

I want to use this method to see saved password in chrome directly in the page where **** are shown, without going into setting / password / search url / click sho / inser win credential / etc...

Until today I have used simply to open Chrome DevTool (F12) and modify on-fly the type of the input (from tpe="password" to type="text")

Then I found a quick system: I saved a bookmark on chrome in which the url is set with the following:

```
    javascript:(function(){
    var ac,c,f,fa,fe,fea,x,y,z;
    ac="type";
    c=0;
    f=document.forms;
    for(x=0;x<f.length;x++){
        fa=f[x].attributes;
        for(y=0;y<fa.length;y++){
            if(fa[y].name.toLowerCase()==ac){
                fa[y].value="text";
                c++;
            }
        }
        fe=f[x].elements;
        for(y=0;y<fe.length;y++){
            fea=fe[y].attributes;
            for(z=0;z<fea.length;z++){
                if(fea[z].name.toLowerCase()==ac){
                    fea[z].value="text";
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Modifica '"+ac+"' applicata su "+c+" oggetti.");
})();
```

This work perfectely, except when the page does not have a `<form>` (i found some) and when `<input>` are inside a frameset or iframe

Here is an example:

https://wificommunity.vodafone.it/

Login module is included in a iframe:

```
<iframe width="192" height="190" frameborder="0" src="/captiveportal/jsp/login_form.jsp" id="login"></iframe>
```

So i would like to have a little help to adapte the code to let it find ALL the input tags, also the one in a iframe or frameset.

Comment: Please re-read yourself before posting to correct misspelled words and grammar.

Comment: thanks so much for your help and corrections. i'm italian and my english is quiet poor....